# What would be the fastest way to compress streaming char arrays in text format using C?

Tags: c, compression

I have very little experience with compression algorithms; my experience just comes from running the tar czvf command. Is there a way to compress a char array in C?

My main focus is speed and memory optimization. I'm receiving data from serial ports, and then writing them out to a log file right now. I want to compress/encrypt the data before I write it to the log file because I have limited harddrive space. I am also storing the information in ASCII format, because I have to pack it with a timestamp. What method should I look into for compressing this information? Or is there some library I can look into to help?

Comment: Try [ZLib](http://www.zlib.net/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zlib has already been mentioned in the comments. Since you mention ASCII, you might be interested in particular in the functions:

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORTVA gzprintf OF((gzFile file, const char *format, ...));
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzputs OF((gzFile file, const char *s));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this lib bookmarked here, but I've never used it.

> LZO is a data compression library which is suitable for data de-/compression in real-time. This means it favours speed over compression ratio.
>
> LZO is written in ANSI C. Both the
>   source code and the compressed data
>   format are designed to be portable
>   across platforms.

http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/